# Unlisted App in Stores

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, app-store-connect

Is it possible to publish an iOS App in App Store and Google Play Store, which is unlisted and can't be found by search? Only people, who have the link to the App in the Store can download it. Is this possible?

Comment: A few moments at google could help you faster than writing this post. Anyway, google play store has private option for organizations only. Check this: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2623322?hl=en

Answer (score 4):

Both Google Play and Apple's App Store have options for publishing Enterprise apps. The two stores have different options and conditions, but it's possible.

Other options that are available to you is to release the app as an Alpha or Beta version for specific people on the Play Store, or simply create an .apk file and allow people to install it without passing through the store.

On the Apple App Store, you also have the option of having your app approved by the review team and then using codes for specific users to redeem on the store (but you only have about 100 of those per version) or submitting the app for TestFlight review (which is a much shorter process), in which case you'll be able to install the app on 1,000 different devices.

I hope one of these options works for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this exact thing is now possible in the Apple ecosystem. It's called "unlisted apps". See [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/). Not sure about Google/Android.